# Extend IdentityUser in a .net standard library

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I have a custom user type for my application which I want it to inherit from IdentityUser but it's in a .net standard library and I don't want Identity package to be in my Domain layer.

what is the best approach for doing this?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity itself is a .NET Standard 2.0 project, so yes, you can use in in any other .NET Standard 2.0 project. All .NET Core extensions are .NET Standard, which means you can easily use them in .NET Framework projects too.

Comment: @AshutoshKushawaha I think it is in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework package and I don't want an EF thing in my Domain

Comment: @h Ebr is it possible to store the user id and password virtually with the encrypted format   and retrieve when we need. I thik this for  authentication  or identity of user